# Bash: Loop though multiple files and print each line from each file and write to a different file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have 3 files with different number of lines. I am trying to loop through the three files and print 1st line from each file into a new file output1.txt and then 2nd line from each file into another new file output2.txt and so on. Because number of lines are different in each file, If there is no entry for file2 and file3 on few lines, it should ignore and print nothing in the subsequent output files created. How can i achieve this in bash?

file1

```
xyz
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

file2

```
123
456
789
```

file3

```
ax1
by2
```

OUTPUT FILES

output1.txt

```
xyz
123
ax1
```

output2.txt

```
abc
456
by2
```

output3.txt

```
def
789
```

output4.txt

```
ghi
```

output5.txt

```
jkl
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

Use `bash` to tell `awk` to do it, that's how bash is meant to be used (and not, for example, to do text processing itself).

e.g. the following awk one-liner writes each input line to a filename constructed from the literal string "output", the current line number of the current input file (awk variable `FNR`) and the literal string ".txt":

```bsh
$ awk '{print > "output" FNR ".txt"}' file*

$ tail output*
==> output1.txt <==
xyz
123
ax1

==> output2.txt <==
abc
456
by2

==> output3.txt <==
def
789

==> output4.txt <==
ghi

==> output5.txt <==
jkl
```

Note: If you have lots of output files (hundreds or more), you may run into problems. With some versions of awk, if you exceed the number of file handles allowed to your process by the kernel and login environment, it may just die with an error.  With other versions of awk (e.g. GNU awk), it may just slow down while it manages which file handles are open for write at any given moment.  Unless some of your input files are hundreds of lines long, it's not likely to be a problem.

The following will work with any version of awk with input files of any length (because it only ever has one output file open for write at a time) but it will be significantly slower *because* it opens the output file for each write and closes it immediately after the write.   Even so, it will still be many times faster than doing this in shell.

```
awk '{
  # use 5-digit zero-padded output filenames for this version
  # e.g. output00001.txt
  out = sprintf("output%05i.txt", FNR);

  if (out in files) {
    # we have written to this file before, so append to it
    print >> out
  } else {
    # first write to this file, so create or truncate it.
    print > out
    files[out]=1
  }
  close(out)
}' file*
```

Comment: `file{1..3}.txt` might do it better though, but not sure which version it is present might require bash4+

Comment: I originally had `file[123]` as the file glob arg to awk, but changed it to `file*`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Comment: @bharathjavvadhi If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.

Answer (score -2):

Below solution my colleague suggested has worked for me. Thank you all for taking time to answer my question. I really appreciate it.

```bsh
# for flattening and merging the file and writing to a tempfile
pr -J -m -t file* --sep-string=';' > mergedfile

# Now you have data in each line which can be looped and redirected to respective filenames based on the loop count
# No.of files will be equal to the biggest file in the input, in this case , you will see 240 files
i=1
while read line; do
  echo "=======file no: $i ========"
  echo $line|sed -e 's@^;@@g' -e 's@;;@@g'|tr ';' '\n' > output${i}.txt
  let i=i+1
done < mergedfile
```

Comment: This does not preserve whitespace in the data, and it may possibly expand certain escape-sequences. It also would produce unexpected results if any line contained filename globbing patterns.

Comment: leaving aside the quirks of plain `read` (without `-r` and clearing `IFS`), `echo` and the unquoted variable expansion, this also seems awfully awkward, and would produce invalid results if the input data contains semicolons. Was the something wrong with the awk solution posted earlier?